# cumulative atlas in QGIS 2.14 and above?

Tags: qgis, atlas, rule-based, rule

I have a question about something which I think is possible but just can't get my head round it, and haven't found any answers online. I'm using $id= @atlas_featureid in QGIS 2.14 to create an set of images from the Atlas tool, and it works fine as usual. However, instead of having each map iterate through the dataset and show one row of data at a time, I'd like it to show one row of data and then add each row of data successively in a cumulative way. I think I can use a rule to achieve this, but not sure how.

Example image: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-326CYkmBxH0/WOUFwYzYv6I/AAAAAAAACIk/bzgu-84DcX8QR23zFItNF2lZXnUGE7SqQCLcB/s1600/gun_homicides_cumulative_2015_100ms.gif

Individual Atlas extract - one day = one map.
[image]

To help explain, see [this gif](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-326CYkmBxH0/WOUFwYzYv6I/AAAAAAAACIk/bzgu-84DcX8QR23zFItNF2lZXnUGE7SqQCLcB/s1600/gun_homicides_cumulative_2015_100ms.gif) I created from a series of maps on US gun crime. Instead of one day's worth of data appearing at a time, I'd like it to build up over time so that on the Jan 31 frame there is 31 day's worth of dots on screen and then it's just a mess of dots by Dec 31 - I know it will probably look bad but I'd like to use it in other projects as well.

Does anyone know how this could be done?

Comment: does `$id<= @atlas_featureid ` work?

Comment: Just gotta say - that's a nice looking design! (horrible theme aside, of course)

Comment: Thanks Nyall, and yes, bad data theme. Success! Thanks a lot Ian, brilliant simplicity. I was over-thinking this. This worked perfectly and the result is in the updated blog post [link] (http://www.statsmapsnpix.com/2017/03/visualising-lot.html) - on its own here as a direct link to gif [link] (https://1.bp.blogspot.com/--ydpPVM8tLQ/WOtUHlPdT_I/AAAAAAAACJo/UB7wLgj2tcYxXBsJZRcnDRNRDc5lpvtUwCLcB/s1600/gun_homicides_cumulative_2015_layered_100ms.gif)

Answer (score 4):

*Just putting into an answer @iant comment, that solved the problem*

If you use

```
$id= @atlas_featureid
```

you will display the current entity.

However, if you use

```
$id <= @atlas_featureid
```

you will display the current entity + the previous ones in a cumulative way.