# Export QGIS Atlas frames showing ALL the features on a given date

Tags: qgis, atlas

Apologies if this has been covered elsewhere, but I'm trying to generate a bunch of frames (to animate later with ffmpeg) using QGIS Atlas + NASA FIRMS data. I'm using the date column from the FIRMS data, in YYYY-MM-DD format. QGIS version is 3.10.1

Using this technique from [this other post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234971/cumulative-atlas-in-qgis-2-14-and-above) to show cumulative points.

[image: $id <= @atlas_featureid]

And here are my Atlas settings before I export them as pngs.

[image: Atlas export options]

Unfortunately this exports a separate png for each features from of the data, rather than grouping all the points under a given date and exporting a single image for that date.

What could I try to export all the points for each date?

Comment: Please add your QGIS version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the principle of the atlas is to create a single map for each features of your layer, so it's logical to have a single map by features.

In your case I suggest a modification / creation of your data. The point is to create a layer with a "row"/ features with multiples points, aggregated by date.

1. `Dissolve` your point layer, see there https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorgeoprocessing.html?highlight=dissolve#dissolve
2. Use `Dissolve field`  : ACQ_DATE -> creation of a new layer e.g. `fire_dissolve_date`
3. Then add this `fire_dissolve_date` layer for your atlas.

Like this you will have a series of map, with points of fire for a single date by map.

And let me know your animation if you publish it!

Comment: This worked like a charm—thank you!

Additional note: I was having trouble with the sort order of the output images, but what seemed to fix it was to make sure the dates were sorted in the attributes table—then uncheck the "sort by" box under the Atlas settings.

Comment: May be it depends on your date format?  It' don't seem logical, i will try to figure out this point.